# Is it possible to prove this using set theory only and no more?

Tags: metric-spaces, connectedness

Got to prove:
If $E$ and $F$ are connected sets, and $A$,$B$ are subsets of $E$ and $F$ respectively (but neither $A$ or $B$ are empty or fill $E$ and $F$entirely). Then $(A\times B)^c$ is connected in $E\times F$.

There is a set of 3 problems in which, the first I tried was wrong because I shouldn't use set theory, but this one seems more plausible. I'm guessing $E$ and $F$ are metric spaces.

Comment: Hint: try first the case where $A^c$ and $B^c$ are single points. Does that give you insight into the general case, especially after recalling that the union of non-disjoint connected spaces is again connected? (By the way, the hypothesis that $A$ and $B$ are nonempty isn't necessary.)

Comment: What does it even mean "prove this using set theory only"?